# How do I select child nodes that don't have a specific parent as an ancestor?

Tags: xslt, xpath

We use CruiseControl for our build server.  It compiles our applications using MSBuild and uses its own XML logger that spits out something like the following XML:

```
<project name="CI">
  <target name="CompileApp">
    <project name="Project1.csproj">
      <target name="build">
        <error>Compilation error one!</error>
      </target>
      <target name="BeforeBuild">
        <project name="Project2.csproj">
          <target name="build">
            <error>Compilation error two!</error>
          </target>
        </project>
      </target>
    </project>
  </target>
</project>
```

I want to transform this into a report that outputs each project's errors.  I don't want to report on the errors in other projects.

```
  Project "Project1.csproj": 1 error(s)
  Error(s):  
  Compilation error one!

  Project "Project2.csproj": 1 error(s)
  Error(s):
  Compilation error two!
```

This is the closest I've gotten, but it's not right.  It doesn't filter out project2's errors when showing project1's errors.

```
<xsl:template>
  <xsl:variable select="//project[.//error]" name="projects.with.errors" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$projects.with.errors" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="project">
   <xsl:variable select="./*[not(project)]//error" name="errors" />
   <xsl:if test="count($errors) > 1">
      <!-- display errors -->
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I filter out any error nodes that have a different project ancestor than my current project node?  I.e., how can I only select descendant error nodes that don't have a project ancestor?

The error nodes can have an arbitrary number of parent elements (usually , but not always).

Comment: Is the first `<project>` tag at the root level?  Are you saying you want to show data from only `<target>` tags that are direct children of the root?

Comment: An error belongs to its first <project> ancestor node.  When I select a <project> node, I want to then select only the errors that belong to it (i.e. only error nodes that have it as the error node's first <project> ancestor)

There may be an arbitrary number of target and other nodes between a <project> and an <error> node.  I've greatly simplified the XML here.

Comment: Nice question (+1). See my answer for a complete and efficient solution. :)

Comment: FYI: The currently selected solution is 3-4 times slower than mine -- even for relatively small XML files (198 lines). For an XML file with 982 lines *the selected solution is 20-30 times slower*. For larger files it may be hundreds of times slower, because *its complexity is O(N^2) -- quadratical*, while mine is sub-linear. But I shouldn't be telling you this -- do your own timing... :)

Comment: @Dimitre: This comment was already made on my answer, reposting it here was unncessary and inappropriate; your comments relate to my answer, not the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quite simple solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//project[.//error]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="project">
    <xsl:variable name="errors" select=".//error[ancestor::project[1]/@name = current()/@name]" />
    <xsl:if test="count($errors) != 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Project &quot;',@name,'&quot;: ',count($errors),' error(s)&#10;Error(s):&#10;')" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$errors" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="error">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#10;')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet basically just calls a template for each `project` element anywhere in the document tree. This template stores a list of all errors in a variable, using an xpath that selects all `error` elements that are a descendant of the current `project` and have the current `project` element as it's first `project` ancestor. Then, if there are any, it just outputs the appropriate header text and applies a template to each error.

I'm using `&#10;` for the new line character here, but if you prefer the windows newline, you can use `&#13;&#10;`.

Minor caveat to this one; you'll end up with a blank line at the bottom of your output, as it adds one at the bottom of every project to separate it from the next.

Comment: Instead of using @name (which may or may not be unique in my situation), I used generate-id().  My errors selector looks like this:  

    <xsl:value-of select="//error[generate-id(ancestory::project[1]) = generate-id(current())" name="errors" />

Comment: Fair enough.. Given that it's project names, I was expecting they would be unique, but at least it's fairly easy to modify as required.

Comment: This solution is remarkably inefficient. Expressions like: `//project[//error]` are good example of a XPath antipattern.

The time complexity is O(N^2), where N is the number of elements in the XML document.

Comment: @Flynn: If I'm a father, I know who are my childs.

Comment: FYI: *This solution is 3-4 times slower than mine* -- even for relatively small XML files (198 lines). *For an XML file with 982 lines it is 20-30 times slower*. For larger files it may be hundreds of times slower, because *its complexity is O(N^2) -- quadratical*, while mine is sub-linear. But I shouldn't be telling you this -- do your own timing... :)

Comment: So what? I didn't say it was fast, I said it was simple. Speed's not always a priority, sometimes simpler and easier to maintain code is. Strictly speaking, you can leave off the `[//error]` predicate anyway, it would just mean the template would get called for all projects, but it would output nothing if there were no errors.

Comment: I take one point though; it should really be `[.//error]`, to represent all descendents of `project` instead of all `error` elements in the document. I've amended it.

Comment: Performance isn't too much of an issue for us.  These get generated infrequently, and are then cached.  Our builds take orders of magnitude longer than the report generation.

I'll update my local files to use .//error, but I thought the . at the beginning was implied.

Comment: No, the . tells XPath to use the current node as a starting point, otherwise it starts from the document root.

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kProjectByName" match="project"
  use="@name"/>

 <xsl:key name="kErrByProject" match="error"
  use="ancestor::project[1]/@name"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select=
    "//project
          [generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('kProjectByName', @name)[1])
           ]
    ">
     <xsl:variable name="vErrors" select=
       "key('kErrByProject', @name)"/>

     <xsl:if test="$vErrors">
         Project <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="count($vErrors)"/> errors.
         Errors:
         <xsl:for-each select="$vErrors">
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<project name="CI">
  <target name="CompileApp">
    <project name="Project1.csproj">
      <target name="build">
        <error>Compilation error one!</error>
      </target>
      <target name="BeforeBuild">
        <project name="Project2.csproj">
          <target name="build">
            <error>Compilation error two!</error>
          </target>
        </project>
      </target>
    </project>
  </target>
</project>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
 Project Project1.csproj: 1 errors.
 Errors:
 Compilation error one!

 Project Project2.csproj: 1 errors.
 Errors:
 Compilation error two!
```

Comment: It's good, but complex, I think. Also, he has commented that *"@name (which may or may not be unique in my situation)"*. So, if you go with "first of a kind" `project` by `@name`, you could loose some deeper `project`.

Comment: @Alexandro: I am not missing any project name -- in fact the code of the template starts with finding all distinct project names.

Answer (score 0):

We are so used to complex requirements, we are puzzled when it appears a more simple, I think.

So, with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="project[../..]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',
            'Project &quot;',@name,'&quot;: ',count(target/error),' error(s)&#xA;',
              'Error(s):&#xA;')" />
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="error">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You get:

```
Project "Project1.csproj": 1 error(s)
Error(s):
Compilation error one!

Project "Project2.csproj": 1 error(s)
Error(s):
Compilation error two!
```

Comment: You haven't paid attention to this comment of the original author:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135926/how-do-i-select-child-nodes-that-dont-have-a-parent-ancestor

Comment: @Dimitre: He've provided input and output. So, I prefer to keep my own logic. In fact, the question being asked to solve their own implementation, is poorly formulated. Should be: "How do I select child nodes that don't have a **specific** parent ancestor"

Comment: I am not criticizing your solution. I just pointed out the fact that the OP clarified the problem with more specific information in his comment. I also find the title confusing.

Comment: @Dimitre @Alejandro Totally agree the title is confusing.  Now accepting applications for a new one!  Suggestions?  I just changed it to be "a specific parent as an ancestor" per Alejandro's suggestion.

Comment: @splattered bits: Good title! But I'm still convinced that this solutions is better. When you are `project`, you know you want all your `target/error` grandchilds. You don't need to filter all your `//error` descendant.